# Hide manage code(C# Code) from .NET Reflector

Tags: c#, .net-reflector

Hi In C# windows application. I need to know by using **.NET Reflector** [.NET_Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector) all source code is viewed by anyone. But I want hide some code(Important secure code) in c# from .Net Reflector.

Anyone help me to hide managed code(C# code) from Reflector. Thanks...

Comment: You can obfuscate you code. Here are some discussion : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163701/how-can-i-obfuscate-my-c-sharp-code-so-it-cant-be-deobfuscated-so-easily

Comment: Also: [.NET obfuscation tools/strategy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/net-obfuscation-tools-strategy)

Answer (score 1):

You can use intellilock from eziriz to do it (3rd party licencing software) http://www.eziriz.com/