# Tool to generation random name for properties and function on the whole solution

Tags: visual-studio, obfuscation

I find tool or extension for Visual Studio 2015 which change all class name, properties, function and other in my solution.

I want that my solution was unreadable but I could build this solution.

I have to give the project an external company

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic. However, to help you, search for _obfuscation tools_

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163701/how-can-i-obfuscate-my-c-sharp-code-so-it-cant-be-deobfuscated-so-easily

Comment: Do you have to give the source code or the compiled assemblies away?

Answer (score 0):

Use ConfuserEx tool to obfuscate your code. This is open source tool which comes in both command line interface and GUI mode. Instruction is written on this site how to use.

Here is link 
https://yck1509.github.io/ConfuserEx/

Download tool from here

https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx/releases