# How can I remove debugging information from my C# application?

Tags: c#, debugging

I am using Visual Studio 2019 to build my C# .NET application, and I want to remove the names of functions/classes from the output file.

I have changed "Debugging information" in the project settings from *Pdb-only* to *None*, but I can still see the symbols by attaching a debugger (such as dnSpy) to the program.

I expect the built .exe file to not reveal the name of my functions and classes.

Comment: .NET includes metadata for reflection purposes. Removing the names of symbols is not possible. This is why there's a market for obfuscation tools to rename them to something unintelligible; making them entirely anonymous is not possible.

Comment: Why? What problem this info causes? The first thought is [obfuscate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19163701/1997232) it, but maybe it's something different?

Comment: We've been using Dotfuscator which replaces the methods & class names with 'a, b, c, d,..' in our client application. There are other, similar obfuscation tools available.

Comment: @Sinatr I am teaching my friend basic reverse engineering for .NET assemblies, and having the symbol names makes it so they do not need to understand and name what each function or class purpose is

Comment: "Basic reverse engineering" means running ILSpy on it and getting back more or less instantly readable C# -- quite easy to teach! Tampering with the names alone has limited use, which is why commercial obfuscation tools go considerably further.

Comment: Reverse-engineering can be quite useful, you tend to be able to file a much better bug report or find a workaround yourself.  Why you are trying to teach somebody such a skill, maximizing the odds he will fail at it is not obvious.  There's no point to that.

Comment: I don't understand you guys. I'm asking a question and you all give me comments about this even though they're unnecessary. Is it that hard to say "no, you can't do that"