# How to protect unity assembly without compiling to IL2CPP?

Tags: unity-game-engine, .net-assembly, obfuscation, assemblies

For a long time we deploy our games in IL2CPP mode to protect unity assemblies, and now I'am looking for techs to make the DLLs unreadable by ilspy, dnSpy and the like, while the DLLs can be read correctly by the runtime (mono), can someone show me how to achieve this?
[image: DLLs unreadable by ilspy]

Comment: IL2CPP doesn't "protect" anything .. you can still decompile them ... I think the keyword you are looking for is [Obfuscate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163701/how-can-i-obfuscate-my-c-sharp-code-so-it-cant-be-deobfuscated-so-easily)

Comment: You definitely need an obfuscator, here a good list: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60054/1480104