# Build an installer for .NET app that can run on Windows and OS X?

Tags: .net, deployment, mono, desktop

I am surprised I could not find this question already asked, so if I simply missed it please notify promptly.

I need to write a very small, fairly simple application in .NET that will be downloaded by end-consumers and installed on their system. Silverlight's sandbox model will not work - it has to be a full-on downloaded, installed executable.

Here's what I know:

- I've developed applications which run in a controlled desktop environment - for example, an IT app that runs on a hundred internal computers.
- I've developed applications using Mono

What I do not know:

- How to create a flexible, robust installer that will work on a myriad of uncontrolled desktop configurations and environments.
- How to do the same with Mono targeted for Mac OSX.
- **What are the common issues in installing a widely-distributed end-user application and how to mitigate them?**

I am looking for the **best resources to fill in my knowledge gaps**.

> #### Related
>
> [Equivalent of a Windows Service on OSX with Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223520/equivalent-of-a-windows-service-on-osx-with-mono)

Comment: (edited, the title wasn't very descriptive, forgot to comment)

Comment: If you definitely don't want any window that is a different kettle of fish than the original question. I would point out that supplying a download link to a windows setup exe verses a mac app bundle is normal and people on both sides expect to have to download one or the other. therefore your real question is how to make said installer enforce (downloading if need be) the .Net runtimes and how to install as either a service/background task on the relative platforms...

Comment: @ShuggyCoUk good point. I don't expect to have a single download for both PC and Mac users. I think my question is not very clear - I believe there are some common issues which anyone who has developed installers for mass-distributed end-user app for both platforms would be aware of and know how to mitigate. I am interested in that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For Windows, consider [Windows Installer XML (WiX)](http://wix.sourceforge.net/). For OSX, you need to generate a .app bundle. [Here is an example](http://www.monobjc.net/index.php?page=cocoa-application) using the nant tasks included with the [Monobjc](http://www.monobjc.net/) project.

Here are some of the major issues you will face:

On Windows:

- Your installer will have to detect
  previous/old versions and
  close/uninstall/migrate as
  appropriate. Both NSIS and WiX have
  mechanisms for this.
- Your installer/app will have to be
  compatible with different versions of
  Windows (XP, Vista, 7), and different
  versions of .NET (2.0, 3.0, 3.5
  eventually). Actually testing this is
  one of the more tedious tasks  you
  face. I strongly recommend having a
  handful of clean virtual machine
  images around for this.

On OSX:

- You will most likely want to ship a standalone application bundle, meaning mono will be bundled within your .app. This will add ~50mb to your distributable.
- You will have to reference different versions of Monobjc to support OSX 10.4 and 10.5, you will need to configure your build to do this, as well as test both versions.
- Make sure that your c# code isn't using Windows/.NET specific calls by running the [Mono Migration Analyzer (MoMA)](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) on your codebase.

Upgrading:

You haven't mentioned how you plan to offer upgrades. NSIS and WiX have the capability to handle upgrades. Make sure you have your build versioning scheme worked out before your deploy the initial version. On OSX, Monobjc can integrate with [Sparkle](http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org/).

Answer (score 6):

There is [bitrock](http://bitrock.com/), which handles your target platforms but costs money

Answer (score 3):

http://www.openlina.com/

They deliver on the build once, run anywhere promise.

Comment: Very neat - I've never seen an OSS project that succeeds in this area.

Comment: the website suggested that common installer was on their road map but not yet implemented unfortunately

Comment: My bad.  When I talked with them at OSCON they demoed apps running in multiple environments and talked about single installer executables so I guess I just assumed they had implemented it.

Comment: no worries - it got me looking into an interesting slant on VM tech thanks

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not be the answer you are looking for.  If your application can survive in the Silverlight sand box, you may want to explore Silverlight 3.0.

Silverlight 3 allows your application to run outside of the browser on Windows and Mac.

Here's an example of setting it up:
http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-3-as-a-Desktop-Application-Out-of-Browser-Applications.aspx

Comment: I need to setup this application to run on startup. It has a minimal GUI, runs more like a local service. I am not sure if Silverlight is the best tool for that.

Comment: this is absolutely the best way to do it if the sandbox fits your needs. The sandbox will be maintained as cross platform for some time, thus aligning your desires with those of the platform maker's...

Comment: @ShuggyCoUk my research indicates out-of-browser Silverlight does not support running as a background process or out of the tray (e.g. windowless). Is this incorrect?

Comment: Hmm, you might be able to set up a startup to go to the silverlight URL... still, not convinced this is right.

Comment: no - the window remains so it sounds like the sandbox will be either very irritating or too limiting for your app. sorry :(

Comment: if you want to experiment then http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882515.aspx is a good starting point. This will let you know if the isolation itself is too limiting for you (sounds like it might be)

Comment: @jcollum: A Windows Service on OS X?

Comment: @John: Indeed. Question is about Windows and OSX. In Windows a Service is a better solution than Silverlight (for the original iteration of the question)

Answer (score 2):

To create an installer there is:

1. [NSIS - Free](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Screenshots)
2. [InstallShield - Paid](http://www.acresso.com/products/is/installshield-overview.htm)

I do not know how know about Macs

Issues:  Computer does not have .Net Framework

Solution: [StackOverflow - The State of Linkers for .NET apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668188/the-state-of-linkers-for-net-apps-aka-please-sir-may-i-have-a-linker-2009-ed)

Comment: NSIS and InstallShield are not cross-platform.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [BitRock's InstallBuilder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com/). From their website:

> BitRock InstallBuilder is a
>   development tool for building
>   crossplatform installers for desktop
>   and server software. With
>   InstallBuilder, you can quickly create
>   professional installers for Linux,
>   Windows, Mac OS X, Solaris and other
>   platforms from a single project file
>   and build environment.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [InstallAnywhere](http://www.acresso.com/products/ia/installanywhere-overview.htm). It allows you to target multiple platforms with one installer project. It will help with dependencies and platform specific issues.

I've used it on LINUX/BSD/Windows deployment, and it worked beautifully. If you had X-windows, you got a GUI, if not a command line install. Windows installer worked with standard windows installer tech, and looked like a professional installer. It supports mac OS X  as well. I highly recommend this software it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As other posters mentioned, [BitRock InstallBuilder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com) supports your target platforms of Windows, Linux and Mac. I want to add that it has been used by the Mono project itself for a while to distribute all-in-one binary installer for Mono runtime. It is also used by other successful Mono-based ISVs like [Codice Software](http://codicesoftware.com)