# Equivalent of a Windows Service on OSX with Mono

Tags: .net, macos, mono

What do I need to do to have my .NET-Mono application run as a background process on OSX and start when the OS starts up? (Assuming the application is otherwise ready to go on OSX)

> #### Related
>
> [Build an installer for .NET app that can run on Windows and OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223203/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ShuggyCoUk notes, that article is very out of date. In 10.4, OS X made some some radical changes. The guide you want to read is [System Startup Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/BPSystemStartup.html). The short answer is "use launchd."

Answer (score 1):

[this article](http://www.osxfaq.com/tutorials/LearningCenter/HowTo/Startup/index.ws) might be a bit out of date but might be of use for OSX.

Since your mono process can run in the unix layer (assuming you have no need for a gui) then this should make things simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You want to put a [plist](http://www.screencast.com/users/Zeus/folders/Jing/media/99de6a66-2acf-4eb6-8b75-091041857d19) (this is an example of running CruiseControl.NET) in /Library/LaunchDaemons and the plist has to be owned by root. Also note as you are using LaunchD the process will always be running as root.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a blog post](http://uselessthingies.wordpress.com/2008/05/18/an-app-without-dock-icon-and-menu-bar/) on what to add to your Info.plist to have your app run in the background and not have a dock icon.