# Can we bundle mono in our installation package?

Tags: .net, linux, unix, mono

Just for thought; can i bundle mono with my application package. So that if not installed then it get installed automatically.

Answer (score 4):

You could, but don't. Instead, just require the distro's Mono packages.

Alternatively, you might use [Mono Linker + mkbundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668188/the-state-of-linkers-for-net-apps-aka-please-sir-may-i-have-a-linker-2009-ed/694631#694631), but this is *not* the preferred way to do things.