# creating a native executable using C#

Tags: c#, windows, compilation, native, exe

What is a way I can a native EXE using C#, I want to compile a basic EXE which will run without the need for the .net framework. I've heard of ngen.exe can anyone give me examples of ngen.exe or any better ways. Also I will have a runtime for the application being generated how can I place it into the application so anybody who is using my language can use its features.

Comment: C++ or Delphi, Delphi would be close but you have to try and code without using .NET libraries

Comment: can Delphi compile a executable?

Comment: Yes, Delphi can compile an executable.

Comment: Here's a question about this very problem as of 2009:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668188/the-state-of-linkers-for-net-apps-aka-please-sir-may-i-have-a-linker-2009-e

Comment: Essentially...take a look at what Mono can do for you.  It's about as close as you can get.

Comment: Perhaps the question should be posed "Is it possible to package a C# executable and runtime so that it can run without having to install the runtime?".

Answer (score 7):

Can't do that. Anything written with C# will require the .NET framework to be installed on the machine in which it runs. NGEN is just an optimization; it does not remove the need for the framework.

To do this you'll need C++ or some other language that does not require a runtime.

Comment: This statement is not strictly true "Anything written with C# will require the .NET framework to be installed on the machine in which it runs." This is only true of the MS implementation

Comment: _A runtime_, regardless if it's Mono or .NET.

Comment: You forgot MonoTouch and Unity3d. Also there's nothing stopping you from writing a C# compiler that doesn't require any framework. These of course are all quibbles since its clear that the OP is targeting windows and using the MS Compiler

Comment: is there a implementation of C# which compiles native?

Comment: @Steven as far as I know not for windows and not right now unless you  include http://llvmsharp.codeplex.com/ which is in Alpha. But who knows maybe someone wrote one and just isn't sharing. Proving Non-Existence is tricky