# Force to run a c# apps with Mono Runtime

Tags: c#, mono, runtime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The State of Linkers for .NET apps (aka “Please Sir, May I have a Linker” 2009 edition)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668188/the-state-of-linkers-for-net-apps-aka-please-sir-may-i-have-a-linker-2009-e)

I have a C# application designed for Mono. I don't have the source code, but just the EXE.

I would like to force this EXE to run with the Mono runtime.

So in order to do this, I would like to create a C# app that does this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.start("MyExe.exe")
```

but to force that `MyExe.exe` runs with the MONO Runtime.

Additionally, I would like to embed the Mono Runtime in the application in order to execute the program without having installing the Mono runtime.

Is this possible?  If yes, how?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, He wants to be sure that mono is the thing that executes this program. Perhaps even if this is windows.  This can be done with mkbundle.