# Mono linker error linking framework assemblies in Hello World

Tags: mono, mono.cecil

I have the same problem as described in *[[Mono-dev] monolinker failing on "hello, world"--any ideas?](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-devel-list/2011-May/037580.html)*.

```
C:\monotest>type test.cs
public class Test
{
    public static void Main() {
        System.Console.WriteLine("BOO");
    }
}

C:\monotest>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-2.10.9\bin\monolinker.bat" -a "test.exe" -c link
Fatal error in Mono CIL Linker
System.ArgumentException: Member 'System.Security.AccessControl.AccessRule' is declared in another module and needs to be imported
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.LookupToken (IMetadataTokenProvider provider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Cecil.SignatureWriter.MakeTypeDefOrRefCodedRID (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Cecil.SignatureWriter.WriteTypeSignature (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Cecil.SignatureWriter.WriteGenericInstanceSignature (IGenericInstance instance) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Cecil.SignatureWriter.WriteTypeSignature (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.GetFieldSignature (Mono.Cecil.FieldReference field) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddField (Mono.Cecil.FieldDefinition field) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddFields (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddType (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.AddTypeDefs () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.BuildTypes () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.BuildModule () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder.BuildMetadata () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.<BuildMetadata>m__18 (Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder builder, Mono.Cecil.MetadataReader _) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Read[MetadataBuilder,MetadataBuilder] (Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder item, System.Func`3 read) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.BuildMetadata (Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition module, Mono.Cecil.MetadataBuilder metadata) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.WriteModuleTo (Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition module, System.IO.Stream stream, Mono.Cecil.WriterParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Write (System.IO.Stream stream, Mono.Cecil.WriterParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Write (System.String fileName, Mono.Cecil.WriterParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.Write (System.String fileName, Mono.Cecil.WriterParameters parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Linker.Steps.OutputStep.OutputAssembly (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Linker.Steps.OutputStep.ProcessAssembly (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Linker.Steps.BaseStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Linker.Driver.Run () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at Mono.Linker.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I haven't tested under Linux, but the referenced example did. The same happens under 2.10.8 and 2.10.9.

I found an open source project that has commented out the call to "throw CreateForeignMemberException (member);" in Cecil, which is what is causing this: *[Simple Assembly Explorer,  svn/trunk/Mono.Cecil/Mono.Cecil/AssemblyWriter.cs](https://code.google.com/p/simple-assembly-explorer/source/browse/trunk/Mono.Cecil/Mono.Cecil/AssemblyWriter.cs?spec=svn459&r=459)*.

The trunk of Cecil on [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) still has that code active. I'm weary of removing a check that I don't understand in the first place.

In Stack Overflow question *[Is there a free tool capable of pruning unused code from a CLI assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772873)*, the author of the Mono linker suggests to compile it yourself:

> Note that all released versions of Mono comes with a compiled version of the linker, but I advise you to compile it yourself.

Why should I need to compile it myself? What can I do to get this working? I'm really just exploring the use of this at this point, but it seems promising.

Comment: I successfully linked this on linux using mono 2.11.4 and monolinker 0.2.0.0 and gmcs (.net 2.0). It failed for .net 4.0 dmcs, with error `Failed to resolve Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue\`1/<InternalGetEnumerator>c__IteratorB`

Comment: It worked under 2.11.4 for me also. These are identical side-by-side installs, so something must have been fixed. Unfortunately 2.11.4 breaks a lot of other unrelated stuff for me.