# Run a non GUI .net Framework application without .net installed

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to run a C# .net Framework application which doesn't have any GUI on a machine without .net Framework installed ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: This may change once .NET ahead-of-time compilation ships with the next version of Visual Studio, but for now, no, you can't. .NET is more than a GUI library: it's a whole infrastructure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the .Net framework is a requirement for running .net applications. 
The .net framework provides the host that runs the .Net code. It's in many ways similar to Java and its virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for a .Net Linker, so that you can remove the .Net framework installation dependency at deployment by linking .NET assemblies together into a single file.
Please see this [relevant post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668188/the-state-of-linkers-for-net-apps-aka-please-sir-may-i-have-a-linker-2009-e) that had good information on linkers. I personally have successfully used the commercial solution [remotesoft](http://www.remotesoft.com/linker/) before.