# How can I make an exe that can run on windows with no other installations

Tags: c#, c++, .net, compilation, exe

I have been looking into c# and c++ compilers and I read that they can be compiled into exe files, however the computer has to have the .NET framework installed for them to work. This is fine for me, the developer, because I have Visual Studio installed, but how can I get it to run on other computers without them having to install the .NET framework manually, the same way games and other programs that I download from the internet work for me? Sorry if this is a noobish type of question, but I'm just getting my feet wet with compiled languages and I don't have a lot of experience yet. Thanks.

EDIT: Hi sorry about any confusion. I'm looking for a way to make my application able to be downloaded or received from wherever I put it, and for the users to be able to use it without having to mess around with installing frameworks and such, especially since they may not be computer savvy users.

Comment: If you are just using C++ (with no managed code) it is possible to build a statically linked project with no external dependencies.  If this is not what you want, then you can add the installer project template to Visual Studio and create an installer for your application (there are also other free and paid install builders available).  MS has redistributible packages for the needed runtime support, these can be added to your installer.  Link to MS Redist: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx

Comment: @RichardCritten: Please use the _answer section_ so that the full range of peer review facilities are available to us when reading your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to link your code statically to the msvc runtime library. If you're writing the compile command yourself, you have to add [`/MT` flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx) when you compile.

Every compiler is different with this. So depending on what compiler you use, you'll have a different answer.

Comment: Nearly, but not quite. The program needs not just the VS runtime, but the .NET Framework, which the OP states will not be available (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/887032/560648). Although I have no idea where the OP intends to obtain a Windows installation without .NET installed. If it turns out that the OP is wrong and doesn't need .NET itself at all, then you're spot on.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're right. I overlooked the .NET framework.

Answer (score 1):

You could download an installer creating program, such as Advanced Installer, Nullsoft Installer, InstallShield etc. and use those and include your prerequisites that way.

However Visual Studio does provide you with ClickOnce applications and it allows you to create an installer as an EXE. You can find more information on the MSDN site using these links:
[How to: Include Prerequisites with a ClickOnce Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873130.aspx) and
[.NET Framework Deployment Guide for Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee942965(v=vs.110).)

EDIT: Looking at the answers have I misinterpreted what you mean?

---

EDT: .NET Native with Windows 10

Of course you could actually achieve this in a standalone executable if it's running on Windows 10 using .NET Native (MSDN Article [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn584397(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: This does not answer the question asked.

Comment: @Ken: I don't know about that. It's certainly not strictly wrong. I think the rest of us are assuming the OP wants a one-shot execution with all dependencies baked into the executable, without "cheating" by automating the separate installation of dependencies. We don't really have any basis for that assumption, though (particularly as the example of games is given); the question is quite unclear.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit How is making an installation cheating? To be fair except for my edit in supporting Windows 10 then is there an alternative to do this to support legacy Windows?

Comment: @Billy: It's cheating at the task of baking the dependencies into the executable, by not doing that thing ;P

Comment: _"search it as I don't have enough RP"_ I don't understand this part.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Okay fair enough when you put it that way. Sorry, I tried to post a link directly to the MSDN article but due to my reputation being only 3 (at the time now 4) I was unable to post a third link.

Comment: @Billy: Aha! I can edit it in if you'd like to write a placeholder.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks! I assume you just mean literally write a placeholder like above (I'm a new contributor you see...)

Comment: Just do whatever you want as long as it's clear and obvious what link you want to go where, and I'll edit it in.

Comment: I've done the edit :)

Comment: I can't do anything with "MSDN Article here" - where is it supposed to link to?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn584397(v=vs.110).aspx is the link