# Run a C# Program without having .NET Framework

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, frameworks, compilation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you compile C# without using the .Net framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551554/can-you-compile-c-without-using-the-net-framework)

im sure it's a common question. I did read about it but I don't know how to actually **do it**.
I did see an answer over here that to remove system.dll and another reference, but I can't because I use them, so I read that I can include the Framework in my program or something like that. but how?

Thanks!

Edit: **I mean to run after I compiled, sorry, my mistake**

Comment: For what reason you want to do that?

Comment: Is what you are asking "How do I package a C# application so it can be deployed on a machine that does not have a .Net framework installed?"  Also, what kind of machines are you imagining to be the target of this?

Comment: Voting to close as "compile" is usually means "to transform source in a language into some sort of executable". Since C# have public standard for the language there is no technical problem to compile it withouth ANY framework. But I don't think it is what Ken wants to do.

Comment: @SLaks and @antelrsoft Yes. I mean to run and to package. I just have programs that I can't just give to friends of mine that we're working on a project because they need to get Framework 4, and they have a problem with it so they remove what they have and than download 4 and than download 2 because of some problems and... well, you see how messy it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that you cannot compile a C# program without the .NET Framework (or equivalent such as Mono) it was written for.  There are some ways you can **run** a program without the framework, but not compile.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would say, no by my opinion. You need "something" that compiles your code into binary. Will be this **.NET Framework**, **Mono**, **MyOwnVeryCool** framework, you have to have some *dependency*. If you think about **.NET platform** you need to compile to **IL**, so *you have* a dependecy from **CLR**, if you *don't want compile to IL*, so it's **not** more .NET platform.
2. Consider the fact also, that on latest Windows OS its already shipped "builtin".

Regards.