# Compile .NET with all dependencies

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you compile C# so it doesn’t need the .NET Framework at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551554/can-you-compile-c-sharp-so-it-doesnt-need-the-net-framework-at-runtime)

I am in the process of developing an application is C# which relies on .NET. The computers that the application will be running on are standard user account running Windows XP.

My question is can I compile my application with .NET without of the client computer having .NET framework? Currently right now the application does not run and at run time it tells me that it is not a valid Win32 application. It will run fine on the .NET computer.

Comment: I asked this question again because the others I found were three years old. I wasn't sure if anything has changed since then. It looks like I am going to have to find a different way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will require installing .net on the client machines, it cannot be deployed as part of the application.

Possibly you could make an installer where .net is a requirement, but .Net will still need to be installed regardless

Answer (score 0):

Short answer. No.

Some dodgy-looking 3rd parties claim to be able to make .net apps run without .net, but frankly (although IANAL) I think they're on shaky ground. Best way to approach this is to author an installer that ensures the .net dependency is installed when the app installs.

Sometimes bugs are found in .net. Because the libraries are maintained by Microsoft via Windows update, these bugs get fixed for you without needing to re-release your app, recompiled with the fixed libraries in them. This is very much to your advantage.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool I've used in the past to do this called XenoCode.

It's probably overkill for the majority of situations, but that type of tool was necessary as .NET is/was not supported in WindowsPE.